# Suggestions for implementing microsoft authentication using graph api in soring boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create Microsoft login authentication service using graph api in spring boot. Not able to find any tutarials for this any suggestions please?

Comment: [How to: Use the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample to use `azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter` package to plugin JWT token filter into Spring Security filter chain.

The sample retrieves user's group membership using Azure AD graph API which requires the registered app to have `Access the directory as the signed-in user` under `Delegated Permissions`. You need AAD admin privilege to be able to grant the permission in API ACCESS -> Required permission.

For the details, you could read [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-sample). Hope it could help you.